# Xiaomi Swipe up brings Browser, how to change behavior?

Tags: browser, xiaomi, search

After updating to the new MIUI 10, swiping up from the home screen now brings the stock browser rather than the former default (Google search).. and there is no option to change that behavior.. how would you restore the original search app??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after *lots* of research... I have come to realize that you should remove the stock browser completely in order to restore Google search app as the default...
removing the browser requires a computer and an app called "Xiaomi ADB/Fastboot Tools by Saki_EU" that can be found here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/wiki/tools